# how to create countdowns in swift that will start after a countdown has finished

Tags: ios, swift, countdowntimer

[New to Swift] 
I am making an app on Swift 5 that displays time left before my next task is to start.

My app:

---

### Task 1: Start at 9.30 am

### Task 2: Start at 10.15 am

*Let's say Current Time: 09.00 am*

### Countdown: Time before next task start = 00:30:02 --> 00:30:01 ...

---

I would like to display countdown of the nearest task.

Currently, I can only have one countdown timer on my viewonLoad() that picks up the current countdown. It continues and once it finishes it does not start next timer after it has finished. I understand I have to deal with Background state at a later date, but since I am slowly starting. My idea is to make sure I can initiate next countdown timer once my current one has expired.

So at any point when I open my app, it will always display countdown till my next task.

```
var count = 30 // calculation simplified ... this data is calc from two different date obj
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    @objc func update() {
        if(count > 0) {
            count = count - 1
            countdownLabel.text = String(count)
        }else{
            timer!.invalidate()
            getNextTaskTimes()
        }
    }

    func getNextTaskTimes(){
        count = 5 // not working
    }
```

How can I achieve this please? Also, is there a better way of doing this? Given that, my user may choose to close the app and come back at a later time, I still would want my countdown to continue in the background.

Any help is appreciated. :D Thanks

Comment: Yes, I put 10 times for a default startup value. How do I 'start over' ?

Comment: It doesn't work applying on the else block. And counter is just a simplified version of the date difference calculation, I am more interested in getting a new clock countdown started after finishing the first one

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood  what you want but shouldn't you just start a new timer in the else part then. `timer!.invalidate(); timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true); getNextTaskTimes()`

Comment: I think this might work too. But the problem is resolved when I do not invalidate the timer as I want to keep continuing my tasks. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized the above code works. I just need to make sure I do not invalidate the timer in the else block. Invalidating the timer just kills it.